# Jaxb project in eclipse indigo

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

When I create a jaxb project in eclipse indigo, it tells me "The currently selected JAXB library provider is invalid" which is eclipselink2.3.0-Indigo
I tried the javanet download jars with no success. i can though try the examples in the demo described here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted
with the exception of the part on MOXy customization. No error when i run, it just does not seem to be doing anything.

What am i missing.
Thanks in advance.
Kamal

Answer (score 8):

**Background Info**

The [Eclipse Indigo release](http://www.eclipse.org/indigo/) offers some new JAXB tooling from the [Dali project](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) (which is part of [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)).  You are now able to create a **JAXB Project**.

**Configuration**

A JAXB project can be configured to use the [reference](http://jaxb.java.net/) or [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation of JAXB.  This can be done via:

1. Right click your JAXB Project
2. Select *Properties*
3. Select *Project Facets*
4. Check the *JAXB* facet (If you are using Java SE 6 set the JAXB version to 2.1, if you are using Java SE 7 then set the JAXB version to 2.2).
5. Click the "Further configuration required" or "Further configuration available" links.

**Using the JAXB RI**

- Choose *Generic JAXB* as your platform
- Choose *JRE* as your JAXB Implementation Type

**Using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**

- Choose *EclipseLink JAXB* as your platform
- Choose *User Library* as your JAXB Implementation
- Click the *Manage Libraries*... icon
- ### Add a new User Library for EclipseLink (the binary can be obtained from http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/).

Comment: After trying a lot of things - the first option worked for me. @Blaise - Thanks a tonne!

Comment: you might need to do a following step. in the facets go to the jaxb and to unlock, than remove it and than add the jaxb and you will see further configuration